# Anchor tag in AMP page reloads entire page

Tags: anchor, amp-html, page-refresh, google-amp

I have the following hyperlink on an AMP page, it's a link to an anchor further down on the page:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/venues/amp#party">party</a>`

The anchor tag is present too:
`<a name="party"></a>`

Now when the user is on URL `https://www.example.com/venues/amp` and clicks the hyperlink, the entire page reloads and shows `https://www.example.com/venues/amp#party`

I don't want the page to reload, I just want to jump to the anchor tag like in a regular web page, so why is this happening? Testing Chrome on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/venues/amp#party">party</a>
```

to

```
<span role="button" tabindex="0" on="tap:customId.scrollTo(duration=500, position=top)"> Go to Target </span>
```

and

```
<a name="party"></a>
```

to

```
 <span id="customId"></span>
```

[**Click here for example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEdPVp)

For more information [**Click Here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events)